# JinqJs and JSON

Tags: javascript, json

The examples for JinqJS I found use simple JSON such as the following:

```
var people = [{Name: 'Tom', Age: 15, Location: 'Port Jefferson'},
            {Name: 'Jen', Age: 30, Location: 'Huntington'},
            {Name: 'Diana', Age: 5, Location: 'Huntington'}];
```

It is then easy to perform actions such as:

```
var b = new jinqJs().from(people).select("Name");
```

How would I extract FullName from the following JSON using jinqJs?

```
var people = [
{
    "nn_rs": {
        "Value": 284
    },
    "nn_ci": {
        "FullName": "John Doe"
    }
},
{
    "nn_rs": {
        "Value": 845
    },
    "nn_ci": {
        "FullName": "Jane Doe"
    }
}];
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the navite code of Javasscript is `map` function for resolve this issue.

```
    var rs = people.map(function(item){
               return item["nn_ci"]["FullName"];
    });
```